# How to compute returns of a Pairs Trading Strategy with different holding periods?

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, returns, cointegration, pairs-trading, benchmark

I am currently working on a project where I am testing a Pairs Trading Strategy based on Cointegration.
In this strategy I am considering to trade a couple of hundred stock pairs every day over a time frame of 3 years. According to this strategy I am holding my trades open until either the take profit condition (revert to mean of spread) or stop loss condition (spread exceeding [mean + 3* standard deviation]) holds.
This means that some trades might be open a couple of days, others might be open for weeks or even months.

My question is now: **How can i calculate the returns of my overall strategy?**

I know how to calculate the returns per trade but when aggregating returns over a certain time period or over all traded pairs I have problems.

Let's say I am trying to calculate returns over 1 year. I could take the average of all the trade returns or calculate *sum(profits per trade of each pair)/sum(invested or committed capital per trade)*, both of these would only give me some average return values.

Most of my single trades are profitable but in the end I am trying to show how profitable my whole trading strategy is, so I would like to compare it to some benchmark, but right now I don't really know how to do that.

One idea I had, was to possibly estimate the average daily return of my trading strategy by:

1. Estimating daily return per trade: (return of trade)/(number of days that trade was open)
2. Taking the average of all the daily returns per trade

Then finally I would compare it to the average daily return of an index over the same time frame. Does this make any sense or what would be a more appropriate approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more appropriate approach is to sum your PNL each day across all of your positions and calculate the return for the book as a whole (assuming I understand your question correctly).

Return should be based on your bankroll/AUM/capital allocation, not your notional positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!
That makes sense to me. So, just to clarify: On days that I do not close any trades, I would have return =0% and only on the days where I actually close trades I have return values?
If I understand your answer correctly, that way I could compare it to the daily return of an index as a benchmark, correct?
How would I approach comparing the performance of my strategy over a longer time frame - say a quarter? Do I take cumulative (daily) returns over the quarter or can I only work with the average of the daily return values over the quarter?

Comment: "On days that I do not close any trades, I would have return =0%" - no, you will have MTM PNL each day (which will likely be non-zero). The value of your positions will be changing while the trades are open.

Comment: "I could compare it to the daily return of an index as a benchmark, correct?" - which index and why? If you have a (possibly) market-neutral strategy, why is an index the appropriate benchmark? Loosely speaking, your benchmark should be a 'substitute good'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! That makes sense. So I am assuming from the trades that we close, we carry on their profit and the investment? How can I measure how much return I would have made, if I would have invested 100k into this strategy? Is it even possible because in the end (lets say after 3 years) we would have all our profits divided by all our ever made investments on trades?  This would again be just an average over all our trades that happened, right?

Comment: Regarding the index, I was thinking about the S&P 500. Your explanation makes sense, I was just thinking, that I could maybe show how this strategy would perform against simply parking all your money in the S&P 500 and sit on it.

Comment: I'd suggest something like the HFRX Equity Market Neutral index might be more appropriate. https://www.hfr.com/hfrx-indices-index-descriptions#. But arguably depends on what the strategies' stated aims are, what their risk factor exposures are, etc.

Comment: Say you have three trades open. At day 10, you have returns Trade_1=10%, Trade_2=-4%, Trade_3=0%. This means that the day 10, your total returns are +6%. The next day 11, the trades have same returns, so returns for day 11 is +6%. On day 12 you close trade 1. This means day 12, your returns are -4%.

And to calculate the end resulting returns, dont forget to use log returns as you pass through time. You can not add returns for day 10 + day 11 + day 12 + .... That is wrong. You need to add log returns.